# View javascript object model in real time

Tags: javascript, browser

Are there tools or techniques (other than repeated console.log() calls) to view the javascript object model used in a web page in real time? eg something like:

```
    firstUser (User)
    -- userName Joe Bloggs (String)
    -- userEmail joe.bloggs@gmail.com (String)
    -- userSelections (Array)
    ----[1,2,4]

    secondUser (User)
    -- userName John Doe (String)
    -- userEmail jogn.doe@gmail.com (String)
    -- userSelections (Array)
    ----[1,2,3]
```

I know this can be achieved using console.log(firstUser) and console.log(secondUser) but it would be useful to be able to display the entire data model so that I can see variables being altered in real time.

Comment: You can set variables to "watch" in your developer tools, but I don't think there's anything that would really do what your want. Watched objects need to clicked to view the contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the debugger of the development tools in Chrome or Firefox.
Just set a break point and view the state of all variables under the scope header.

Comment: That's just what I was looking for thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One option is using the `watch` panel on the right inside the `source` tab to help you monitor different variables

[image]

You could also use the `console.table()` method (instead of `console.log`) which displays tabular data as a table.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is configure the logger package ( I really recommend pinojs ) and configure a "log level" strategy for your application, you can read more about [here](https://betterprogramming.pub/application-logging-best-practices-a-support-engineers-perspective-b17d0ef1c5df)

But you also can do that:

```js
console.log(JSON.stringefy(user))
```